# Puzzling Double integral

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I was asked to solve this double integral:
Compute the area between $y=2x^2$ and $y=x^2$ and the hyperbolae $xy=1$ and $xy=2$ in

$$ \iint dx \,dy$$

I tried to solve it starting with considering that

$$x^2 \leq y \leq 2x^2 $$

suitabile for integration interval in $y$, obtaining the incomplete form

$$ \int^{x^2}_{2x^2} \int_\ldots^\ldots dx \,dy$$

but I also have
$$1 \leq xy \leq 2$$ and I would obtain a result in which I still have one independent variabile.

Please, can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find some inspiration [here](https://www.math24.net/change-variables-double-integrals-page-2/#example3).

Comment: If you have $\displaystyle \int_{x^2}^{2x^2} \cdots \, dy,$ then that's got to be INSIDE an integral with respect to $x,$ i.e. you'll need $$ \int_\cdots^\cdots \left( \int_{x^2}^{2x^2} \cdots \, dy \right) \, dx. $$ Otherwise there is no quantity called $x$ from which you can compute the bounds $x^2$ and $2x^2.$ However, if you do it that was rather than by a change of variables, it will be something of a mess at best, as you can see by looking at the graphs.

Comment: @ClydeA.Jansen Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: You're right! ;) sorry

Comment: @ClydeA.Jansen Never mind! I think that there should be an automatic method to recall that when an OP is answered it should be accepted. Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider the change of variables

- $u=x^2\implies 1\le u\le 2$
- $v=xy\implies 1\le v\le 2$

and

$$dudv=|J|dxdy=\begin{vmatrix}2x&0\\y&x\end{vmatrix}dxdy=2x^2dxdy\implies dxdy=\frac1{2u}dudv$$

Answer (score 4):

$y \in [x^2, 2x^2]$ can be interpreted as $\frac{y}{x^2} \in [1,2].$

Consider the change of variables

- $u = \frac{y}{x^2} \in [1,2]$
- $v = xy \in [1,2]$

The Jacobian is given by

$$\frac1J = \begin{vmatrix} u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} -\frac{2y}{x^3} & \frac1{x^2} \\ y & x
\end{vmatrix} = -\frac{3y}{x^3} = -3u$$

so $$dx\,dy = |J| \,du\,dv = \frac1{3u} \, du\,dv$$

Therefore you need to calculate

$$\int_{[1,2]^2} \frac{1}{3u}\,du\,dv= \frac13\ln 2$$

Answer (score 1):

Plot the four functions. See where they intersect. Once you do, you will find that you can rewrite this integral as:

$$\displaystyle \int_{ \tfrac{1}{ \sqrt[3]{2} } }^1\left( 2x^2-\dfrac{1}{x}\right)dx + \int_1^{\sqrt[3]{2}}\left(\dfrac{2}{x}-x^2\right)dx$$